# How i remove accordion/fusion-panel in Python?

Tags: python, html, list, pycharm, panel

I need help! I program this:

```
toggle=[]
for i in soup.find_all('article', {'class': 'post post-113572 type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-kurzprogramm'}):
    per_toggle=i.find('div')
    print(per_toggle)
    toggle.append(per_toggle)


    New_toggle=[]
    for each in toggle:
        new_each = str(each).replace('<br/', '')
        pattern = re.compile('<.*?>')
        result = re.sub(pattern, '', new_each)
        print (result)
        New_toggle.append(result)
        df=pd.DataFrame(New_toggle)
```

but I have one problem: my output is the text that I want. But sometimes this happens:

```
#accordion-113572-1 .fusion-panel:hover{ border-color: #d4d4d4 } #accordion-113572-1 .fusion-panel { border-color:#d4d4d4; }.fusion-accordian  #accordion-113572-1 .panel-title a .fa-fusion-box{ color: #ffffff;}.fusion-accordian  #accordion-113572-1 .panel-title a .fa-fusion-box:before{ font-size: 13px; width: 13px;}.fusion-accordian  #accordion-113572-1 .panel-title a{font-size:19px;color:#191919;font-family:""Barlow Condensed"";font-weight:500;}.fusion-accordian  #accordion-113572-1 .toggle-content{font-size:20px;color:#000000;font-family:""Barlow"";font-weight:regular;}.fusion-accordian  #accordion-113572-1 .fa-fusion-box { background-color: #009ee0;border-color: #009ee0;}.fusion-accordian  #accordion-113572-1 .panel-title a:not(.active):hover, #accordion-113572-1 .fusion-toggle-boxed-mode:hover .panel-title a { color: #009ee0;}.fusion-accordian  #accordion-113572-1 .panel-title .active .fa-fusion-box,.fusion-accordian  #accordion-113572-1 .panel-title a:not(.active):hover .fa-fusion-box { background-color: #009ee0!important;border-color: #009ee0!important;}.fusion-accordian  #accordion-113572-1 .panel-f0b74f27ef9a21ca8 .panel-title a{}.fusion-accordian  #accordion-113572-1 .panel-f0b74f27ef9a21ca8 .toggle-content{}
```

How can I delete this thing?